# encoding bytes to string column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've made a script that converts a bytes column in my csv to string:

```
with open('testfile.csv', 'r') as file, open ('testoutput.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    writeCSV = csv.writer(f_out,delimiter=';',quotechar='"',lineterminator= '\n')


    for row in readCSV:

        byte_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str.encode(row[3]))
        decoded = byte_string.decode('utf-8')
        row[3]=decoded
```

the script probably isn't pretty, but it seems to work.

Is there a way to do the same thing with Pandas? I've multiple things but can't seem to modify the column in the end.

I did manage to convert the column and store it in a list, but I'm not sure how to replace the column with the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out something along what follows?

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = 'YOUR_FILE_NAME'
encoding = 'utf-8' # or alternatively 'ISO-8859-1', etc...
pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding = encoding)
```

Comment: Thank your for your response. The issue is that only 1 column is in bytes. So I just need to read in the entire CSV, encode 1 column and store (replace) it back in the `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code,

```
with open('testfile.csv', 'wb') as test:
    for i in range(6):
        test.write(bytearray('nothing;nothing;nothing;something%s\n'%i, 'utf-8'))
```

... which created this file,

```
nothing;nothing;nothing;something0
nothing;nothing;nothing;something1
nothing;nothing;nothing;something2
nothing;nothing;nothing;something3
nothing;nothing;nothing;something4
nothing;nothing;nothing;something5
```

Then I ran this,

```
>>> newColumn = []
>>> with open('testfile.csv') as file:
...     readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
...     for row in readCSV:
...         newColumn.append(row[3])
...         
>>> newColumn
['something0', 'something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4', 'something5']
```

I had a minimal Pandas df like this.

```
>>> df
   A
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7
5  8
```

I added `newColumn` like this.

```
>>> df['newColumn'] = newColumn
>>> df
   A   newColumn
0  3  something0
1  4  something1
2  5  something2
3  6  something3
4  7  something4
5  8  something5
```

I would say that, since `csv` reads strings only it was unnecessary to invoke any encoding machinery here.

Comment: Thank your for your response. The bytes in the column look like: `ez??R?+??a)???Cs` and the converted bytes look like: `ZXo_P1I_Kz8_YSk_Pz9Dcw==`. I don't see how not invoking encoding machinery, would end up having this "encoded" bytes string into my `dataframe`. Maybe I'm missing the point (still new to Python).

Comment: You're right. It depends where the bytes come from. I don't think you're missing the point.

Comment: What is the data supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
import csv
import base64
import pandas as pd


bytes_Column = []

with open('testfile.csv') as file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in readCSV:
        decoded_Bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str.encode(row[3])).decode('utf-8')
        bytes_Column.append(decoded_Bytes)



df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv', sep=';', header=None)
del df[3]
df.insert(3, 'ConvBytes', bytes_Column)
```

However, if anyone know a faster or better way to do this directly in pandas I would sure like to hear about it!